# Range of the function $f(x) = \frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}$

Tags: calculus, functions

Plotting the function $f(x) = \frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}$ we can see the range is $[-1,1]$.

Now I was told to do $f(x)=y$ and isolate $x$ doing this I have, using the quadratic formula $x=\frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}$ then $$range f(x)= domain \frac{1\pm \sqrt{1-y^2}}{y}$$.

But this domain does not include $0$ and $0=f(0)$ so $0$ must be in the range, what am I missing?

Comment: Is there any reason to think that the domain is not the whole of $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Suppose $f(x)=3$ then $ \frac{2x}{x^{2}+1}=3$ this quadratic equation has no solution so the range is not the whole real line.

Comment: @Sonny That means that $3$ is not in the range of $f$. This does not mean that $f$ has no domain.

Comment: When $f(x)=0$, you can't apply the quadratic formula. That's like trying to solve$$ax+b=c$$using the quadratic formula.

Comment: yes, sorry, the domain is not the whole real line, since the $1-y^2$ must be non negative...yes the domain of the original function is the real line, but that is not my question

Comment: No... plugging values in for $y$ gives you the *range*. Plugging values in for $x$ gives you the *domain*.

Comment: I saw my mistake, I cant use the formula when $y=0$ because I will get $2x=0$, thank you

Answer (score 3):

$y = \frac {2x}{x^2+1}\\
yx^2 - 2x + y = 0$

And then you use the quadratic formula to find values of $y,$ such that $x$ can be a real root of the polynomial.

All good.

What happens at $y = 0$?

$yx^2 - 2x + y = 0$ ceases to be a quadratic and the quadratic formula is not applicable.

Answer (score 1):

A plot of the function is as good as finding the range. Here a "plot" means sketching the general shape of the function, marking precisely the turning points and so on using calculus, and checking what happens as $x \to \pm \infty$. The method you are trying to use (by finding an inverse function) will also eventually work, but is much harder because this function does not have an inverse. You would have to cut the domain up into three pieces and find an inverse on each.

If you've found the turning points and limiting behaviour of the function, you can for sure say what the range is just from a plot. (And in my opinion, this is way more convincing than doing delicate algebra to find partial inverses.)

Comment: *(And in my opinion, this is way more convincing than doing delicate algebra to find partial inverses.)* Many proof-writing classes will explicitly discourage a student from doing this, because a graph is absolutely not a proof.

Comment: @user296602 won't you have to use a graph anyway, to figure out the chunks of the domain where the function is invertible? And I don't really mean a single picture of the function as a proof, I mean a sketch, with worked derivatives and limits backing up the fact that this curve has only two turning points, is monotonic over these three regions, etc etc.

Comment: A graph may make you believe that $\ln(x)$ has a range of $(-\infty,c)$ for some constant $c$, since $\ln(x)$ appears to flatten out really quickly. But doing the algebra will quickly tell otherwise.

Comment: OTOH, I believe that checking a graph is an easy and sometimes intuitive way to ***check oneself*** on these problems, but it is definitely not for **proving**.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I must have been unclear: when I said "plot", I really meant using calculus to find the turning points and shape of the curve, and using limits to check what happens as $x \to \pm \infty$, and drawing all this information onto a graph.

Comment: Hm... okay. That is definitely what I would recommend then (+1)